# В каком случае будет лучшая производительность?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть задача сделать перевод базы данных на 15 языков. В базе данных большой объем данных, наибольшая таблица весит около 4гб.

В каждой таблице `table` есть несколько полей `text` типа MEDIUMTEXT которые нужно перевести на 15 языков.

Как лучше организовать хранение переведенных 15ти языков? Создать в `table` ячейки `en_text`,`fr_text` и тд, либо же лучше на каждый из языков копировать таблицу типа `en_table`,`fr_table` ?

Comment: Вариант с использованием двух таблиц рассматриваете? Первая `table`, вторая `table_translate`.

Answer (score 0):

Возможный вариант.

1. Шардим вертикально все таблицы, содержащие мультиязычные поля, и выносим такие поля в отдельные таблицы. Вяжем 1:1 (FK + UNIQUE).
2. Для каждого языка создаём отдельную БД. Выносим таблицы с мультиязычными полями туда.
3. В процессе работы текущей является БД с языковыми таблицами. Таблицы с числами/датами/english-only - в отдельной БД. Соответственно рефы на таблицы с языковыми данными идут без указания БД, а на общие - с указанием. Переключение языка - одной инструкцией типа `USE ru_ru`, ну и плюс рефреш всего языкозависимого.

Есссно смиряемся с фигнёй типа

```
SELECT main.table1_0.id, COALESCE(table1_1.text, en_us.table1_1.text)
```

Comment: параметры в `coalesce` местами поменять :) если фреймворк какой используется, то смирятся будет проще, по крайней мере частично ORM позволит не писать все `main.table_0.*` вручную, да и быть может остальным получится упростить. или дополнительно добавить набор вьюшек, решающих этот вопрос.

Comment: @teran *параметры в coalesce местами поменять* ?? Вообще-то если есть для текущего языка в текущей БД - берём его, а если перевода нет - берём стандартный (в показанном случае англоязычный). А если поменять местами - так фигня ж получится... а вьюшки скорости уж точно не добавят - только что упростят текст, скрыв все эти COALESCE.

Comment: а, точно. у нас же БД с языком основная. че то подумалось, что на `en_us` переводим. вьюшки да, скорость не добавят. Но если есть небольшие таблицы, то вполне себе можно использовать.